# Different shape when indexing numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to read a 'PNG' file as a numpy array. I do it with the cv2 library, cv2.imread('image') which returns a numpy array. When I print out its shape, I get (6784, 5216, 3) which I actually want. But when I try to iterate within the array with array[1] or array[0], in both cases I get 5216 outputs. Thus, I get outOfBoundIndex error. Any way I could also see the other pixels between the 5216th index and 6784?

Adding code:

```
path = "/home/y0b8k/Projects/y3-ogam/gt_20/train_2.png"
ar = cv2.imread(path_copy, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

My loop before was as you can see below. It actually reads the values, and tries to color a new output image on my will.

```
x, y = 0, 0

while y < mask.size[1]-1:  

    while x < mask.size[0]:
        value = pix[x,y]
        print(x)
        if value[0] == 3:
            col = [64,173,38,255]
            ar[x,y] = col
        if value[0] == 5:
            #print(ar[x,y])
            col = [203,0,0,255]
            ar[x,y] = col
        if value[0] == 7:
            col = [30,50,250,255]
            ar[x,y] = col
        if value[0] == 4:
            col = [100,100,100,255]
            ar[x,y] = col
        else:
            col = [255,255,255,255]
            ar[x,y] = col
        x += 1
    y+=1
    x= 0

cv2.imwrite("çıktı.png",ar)
```

Comment: "Any way I could also see the other pixels between the 5216th index and 6784?" No, they don't exist. You've already shown that the image has only 5216 columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for row in png:
    for pixel in row:
         # do stuff
```

Should iterate through all of the pixels.

```py
for pixel in array[0]:
    # do stuff
```

Would run 5216 times (the top row of pixels), but I can't tell if this is what you're doing because you didn't post the code